# How can bash interpret a zero-length argument from an expanded string?

Tags: macos, bash, sed

On OSX, running sed to edit in place works by passing a zero-length argument like this:

```
find . -name "*.java" -print | xargs sed -f src/main/scripts/remove_snippets.sed -i ""
```

However, putting the `-i ""` into a shell variable does not work:

```
dashi='-i ""'
find . -name *.java -print | xargs sed -f src/main/scripts/remove_snippets.sed $dashi
```

Instead of editing in place the `""` gets interpreted as a literal string to use for the backup extension, leaving a directory of java files named `*.java""`.

How can bash be told to interpret the `""` as an empty argument rather than an argument containing two double-quotes?

Comment: Why would you want to have that in a variable, though? See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Because of cross-platform issues with sed, where BSD versus GNU versions have different expectations for `-i`.

Comment: How about `emptymaybe=yes; sed -i ${emptymaybe+""} '...'` with an unset `emptymaybe` on Linux?  Unlike the array approach, it should be portable to classical Bourne (I hope ... don't have a Mac to test on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array.

```
dashi=(-i "")
find . -name *.java -print | xargs sed -f src/main/scripts/remove_snippets.sed "${dashi[@]}"
```

Comment: That's a whole heap easier than the `eval` alternative!